# Is the partial trace of a mixed state always mixed? If not, are there natural examples where the partial trace of a mixed state is a pure state?

Tags: quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

I know that the partial trace of a pure entangled state must be mixed and that of a product pure state must be pure; but I couldn't find an answer to my above question.

Answer (score 9):

Start with a pure qubit and a mixed qubit, then trace out the mixed qubit. The overall state goes from mixed to pure.

Answer (score 4):

Writing out Craig's answer explicitly (I personally find explicit examples helpful):

$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2} \lvert 0 \rangle_{_A} \lvert 0 \rangle_{_B} \langle 0 \rvert_{_A} \langle 0 \rvert_{_B} + \frac{1}{2} \lvert 0 \rangle_{_A} \lvert 1 \rangle_{_B} \langle 0 \rvert_{_A} \langle 1 \rvert_{_B}
$$
traces out to
\begin{align}
\rho_{_A} &= \lvert 0 \rangle_{_A} \langle 0 \rvert_{_A}
\\
\rho_{_B} &= \frac{1}{2} \lvert 0 \rangle_{_A} \langle 0 \rvert_{_A} + \frac{1}{2} \lvert 1 \rangle_{_A} \langle 1 \rvert_{_A} 
.
\end{align}

Since all the above density operators are diagonal, it is easy to see that $\rho$ and $\rho_{_B}$ are mixed states while $\rho_{_A}$ is a pure state.

Comment: Makes sense. $\rho$ is a product state of a mixed ($\rho_B$) and a pure ($\rho_A$) state. Tracing out the pure state gives the mixed state.

Comment: A follow-up question. Is there a mixed state which is not a product of a mixed and a pure state (so, it could be a product of 2 mixed states or it could not be a product state at all) such that it has a pure partial trace?