# Pure state of a system and mixed states of subsystems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

If we have a system that consists of 2 subsystems A and B. Lets say that the quantum state of the total system $|\Psi\rangle_{AB}$ is a pure state, is it possible that the individual states of the subsystem can be:

1. Quantum states of them (that means each state of each subsystem can be expressed as a linear superposition of the basis ket of the respective Hilbert space) and not only eigenstates?
2. **Mixed states?** (main thing that I want to know)

Comment: Example, subsystem A has a basis ket, which are in the most common case eigenvectors of the hamiltonian and you can express every other quantum state as a linear combination of them.

Comment: no, whether, even though  the state of the total system is a pure state, the states of the subsystems, whose tensor product gives us the total state of the system, whether these states can be mix states, or no?

Comment: No but still that doesn't answer my question. $|\Psi\rangle_{AB}=|\Psi\rangle_{A}\times |\Psi\rangle_{B}$. If $|\Psi\rangle_{AB}$ is a pure state (total system state) can the subsystem state's be mixed, or no?

Comment: or : total state=pure => states of the subsystems=pure & total state=mixed => states of the subsystems=mixed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130194/discussion-between-imbaf-and-jakob).

Comment: Related: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468766/can-the-reduced-state-of-a-mixed-entangled-state-be-pure) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/373028/is-the-partial-trace-of-a-mixed-state-always-mixed-if-not-are-there-natural-ex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP specified the question in the comments, which we'll interpret as follows: Consider a bipartite system $\mathscr H = \mathscr H_1 \otimes \mathscr H_2$ and a density operator $\rho$ on $\mathscr H$. If $\rho$ is pure, does this imply that its reduced density matrices $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are pure? Further, does a mixed $\rho$ imply that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are mixed?

The answer to both questions is, in general, no. For the case of a pure $\rho$ it is easy to verify (cf. [Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition)) that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues and are pure if and only if $\rho$ is a product state.

For example, if $\rho$ corresponds to a maximally entangled [Bell state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state) of a two-qubit system, then its reduced density matrices are maximally mixed.

To answer the second question, let us consider a mixed density matrix $\rho_1$ on $\mathscr H_1$ and a pure density matrix $\rho_2$ on $\mathscr H_2$. Then $\rho \equiv \rho_1 \otimes \rho_2$ is a density matrix on $\mathscr H$. We compute:
$$\mathrm{Tr} \,\rho^2  = \mathrm{Tr}\, \rho_1^2 \, \mathrm{Tr} \,\rho_2^2 = \mathrm{Tr}\, \rho_1^2<1 \quad ,$$

which shows that $\rho$ is mixed. Obviously, $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are the reduced density matrices of $\rho$. Thus, it is not necessary for the reduced density matrices of a mixed state to be mixed as well.